# Linux shell IFS change splited string content

Tags: linux, shell

I use linux shell IFS to split a string, but why IFS change my string as blow pic:
i want to get "*py", but because there is test.py in the same path, IFS change "*py" into test.py

[image]

my test_split.sh is at blow:

```
OLD_IFS=${IFS}
echo -e "OLD_IFS: ${OLD_IFS}"
IFS='|'
echo -e "IFS: ${IFS}"

STRING="HELLOWORLD|*.py"
temp_str=[]
temp_str=($STRING)

IFS=${OLD_IFS}
echo -e "IFS: ${IFS}"
echo -e "${temp_str[0]}"
echo -e "${temp_str[1]}"
```

it execute result:
[image]

I want to ask why IFS change *.py into test.py?
How to avoid it?
Thank you!

Comment: Please post code in form of text ONLY in your question. If you post samples/codes in images then no one can test them. So kindly do update your question and let us know then.

Comment: You are confusing when to use IFS. With `STRING="HELLOWORLD|*py"`, just use parameter expansions to separate the parts, e.g. `first="$(STRING%|*}"` and `second="$(STRING#*|}"`. Now `first="HELLOWORLD"` and `second="*py"`. You generally change `IFS` when you want to control word-splitting on a `read`. (You could do a kludge and do `IFS=$'|'` and `array( $(echo $STRING) )` to have `array[0]="HELLOWORLD"` and `array[1]="*py"`, but that klidge with a command-substitution isn't really the way to do it.)

Comment: Aside from the valid comments above, your approach to restore `IFS` via `OLD_IFS` won't work in every case. bash distinguishes the case that IFS is set and empty, and that IFS is unset. See the bash man page, section _Special Parameters_. In your code, IFS would always be set afterwards. You don't properly restore the state where IFS was unset initially.